# Swagger UI does not sent "origin" header

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, swagger-ui

I using Swagger UI (http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html) with OpenAPI 3.0.
I have configured it to add `Authorization` and `Origin` header parameters to the request. I am using `@ApiImplicitParam` annotation in my Spring Boot application for that.

The problem is that Swagger UI does not send `Origin` amongst the other header parameters.
I can see

```
-H "Origin: https://localhost"
```

in the curl command it builds, but it does not send the origin to the server. The rest of the parameters are fine.
At the same time generated "curl" command sends the origin just file.

How can I make the Swagger UI send everything like its curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Origin` is a [forbidden header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), meaning it is controlled by the browser itself and cannot be changed from JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. It's interesting that curl and Postman let me set it :)

Comment: I understand that I cannot modify the Origin, there is logic there. But why I am not getting a real value from a browser?

Comment: _"But why I am not getting a real value from a browser?"_ `Origin` is not added to same-domain GET and HEAD requests and in some other cases - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin and https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#origin-header